# Why should I use NIO for TCP multiplayer gaming instead of simple sockets (IO) - or: where is the block?

Tags: java, android, sockets, nio, multiplayer

I'm trying to create a simple multiplayer game for Android devices. I have been thinking about the netcode and read now a lot of pages about Sockets. The Android application will only be a client and connect only to one server.

Almost everywhere (here too) you get the recommendation to use NIO or a framework which uses NIO, because of the "blocking".
I'm trying to understand what the problem of a simple socket implementation is, so I created a simple test to try it out:

My main application:

```
[...]
Socket clientSocket = new Socket( "127.0.0.1", 2593 );
new Thread(new PacketReader(clientSocket)).start();
PrintStream os = new PrintStream( clientSocket.getOutputStream() );
os.println( "kakapipipopo" );
[...]
```

The PacketReader Thread:

```
class PacketReader implements Runnable
{
    Socket m_Socket;
    BufferedReader m_Reader;

    PacketReader(Socket socket)
    {
        m_Reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    }

    public void run()
    {
        char[] buffer = new char[200];
        int count = 0;
        while(true)
        {
            count = m_Reader.read(buffer, 0, 200);
            String message = new String(buffer, 0, count);
            Gdx.app.log("keks", nachricht);
        }
    }
}
```

I couldn't experience the blocking problems I should get. I thought the read() function will block my application and I couldn't do anything - but everything worked just fine.
I have been thinking: What if I just create a input and output buffer in my application and create two threads which will write and read to the socket from my two buffers? Would this work?
If yes - why does everyone recommend NIO? Somewhere in the normal IO way there must a block happen, but I can't find it. 
Are there maybe any other benifits of using NIO for Android multiplayer gaming? I thought that NIO seems to be more complex, therefore maybe less suited for a mobile device, but maybe the simple socket way is worse for a mobile device.

I would be very happy if someone could tell me where the problem happens. I'm not scared of NIO, but at least I would like to find out why I'm using it :D

Greetings

-Thomas

Comment: I don't see any reason at all to use NIO in a client, unless it is going to connect to thousands of servers.

Answer (score -1):

The blocking is, the read() will block current thread until it can read data from socket's input stream. Thus, you need a thread dedicate on that single TCP connection.

What if you have more than 10k client devices connected with your server? You need at least 10k threads to handle all client devices (assume each device maintain a single TCP connection) no matter they are active or not. You have too much overhead on context switch and other multi-threads overhead even only 100 of them are active.

The NIO use a selector model to handle those clients, means you don't need a dedicate thread for each TCP connection to receive data. You just need to select all active connections (which has data already received) and to process those active connections. You can control how many threads should be maintained in server side.

Comment: He's writing a client.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**
This answer is kind of not exactly answering about what OP asked. For client side its fine because the client is going to connect to just one server. Although my answer gives some generic idea about Blocking and Non Blocking IO.

I know this answer is coming 3 years later but this is something which might help someone in future.

In a Blocking Socket model, if data is not available for reading or if the server is not ready for writing then the network thread will wait on a request to read from or write to a socket until it either gets or sends the data or
times out. In other words, the program may halt at that point for quite some time if it can't proceed. To cancel this out we can create a thread per connection which can handle out requests from each client concurrently. If this approach is chosen, the scalability of the application can suffer because in a scenario where thousands of clients are connected, having thousands of threads can eat up all the memory of the system as threads are expensive to create and can affect the performance of the application.

In a Non-Blocking Socket model, the request to read or write on a socket returns immediately whether or not it was successful, in other words, asynchronously. This keeps the network thread busy. It is then our task to decide whether to try again or consider the read/write operation complete. Having this creates an event driven approach towards communication where we can create threads when needed and which leads to a more scalable system.

Diagram below explains the difference between Blocking and Non-Blocking socket model.
[image]

Comment: A socket is almost always 'ready for writing'. The network thread won't block on writing unless both the sender's send buffer and the receiver's receive buffer are full, which would indicate that the sender is overrunning the receiver by a considerable amount. Asynchronous I/O is not the same thing as non-blocking I/O. The C10K fallacy was exposed ten or more years ago. There are servers out there with hundreds of thousands of threads. In any case it is irrelevant, as he is writing a client.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the buffer stuff. 
Wont agree to your thousands of thread statement because what I said is that it is just bad. Its not optimal. We should not be just creating threads which are doing nothing. I am not saying its not possible. And yeah for client sure its irrelevant.